# How to save geotag photos in pdf format

Tags: geotagging

I geotag photos in but accidentally save in jpeg format. Is there a way to save the geotag photos to pdf format? with the details on it?

Comment: Which software you use for PDF creation?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want a PDF file that displays the image with the geotag data superimposed on top? I don't think this is a common requirement, so I just want to be clear that is what you want.

Comment: It might also help if you say _why_ you want this. There might be a simpler way to get what you ultimately want.

Comment: A PDF with a raster image is mostly a JPEG with some more information. What do you expect to gain when using PDF?